# ODE with different number of components, typo?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

This is stated in book:
$$
\frac{d \mathbf{x}(t)}{dt} =
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),t) + \mathbf{L}(\mathbf{x}(t),t) 
\mathbf{w}(t)
$$
where $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^D$ and $\mathbf w :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^S$.

Question 1:

Isn't it wrong that the range of $\mathbf w$ is $\mathbb R^S$? Shouldn't it have the same number of components as $\mathbf x$, i.e., $\mathbb R^D$?

Question 2:

From the equation, is it correct to say that the functions are on the form:
\begin{align}
\mathbf f: \mathbb R^D \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^D \tag{1} \\
\mathbf L: \mathbb R^D \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^D \tag{2} 
\end{align}

Comment: $\mathbf{L}$ is a $D\times S$ matrix, so that $\mathbf{Lw}$ is a $D$ dimensions vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like a dynamical system with control input, with $\mathbf{w}(t)$ being the control input. If this is the case:

Ad question 1: No, the control input need not have as many components as the state vector. The function $\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{x}(t), t)$ describes how the actuation of $\mathbf{w}(t)$ affects the change of the state vector. $\mathbf{L}$ is therefore a function of the form:

$\mathbf{L}: \mathbb{R}^{D} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{D \times S}$